# Simple yet frustrating Listbox and Texbox search again

Tags: c#, winforms, indexing

I have spent few days searching everywhere for a solution to this.
This is for C# with Visual Studio 2013 (ya, I am a newbie):

- two textboxes (Last name and First Name) and a listbox with 5 names (Higgins M, Higgins J, King J, Tran A, Dempsey S). I set listbox property as sorted.
- if I select Higgins J in listbox, then the word Higgins should appear in Last Name textbox and J should appear in First Name textbox.
- if I type Higgins in Last Name textbox, Higgins J should be the selected item in listbox (Higgins J will be selected before Higgins M). If I type M in the First Name textbox, the selected item should change from Higgins J to Higgins M.

but....here are the problems that made me decide to create an account here:

1. If I type Hi or Hig instead of Higgins, it has to stay that way, it does not become Higgins in the textbox. Only the index/highlight in listbox is changed, not the entry in textbox (whatever I type in the textbox stays). I suspect the events that I use are the reason I cannot get this done. Textbox_textchanged and listbox_selectedindexchanged. So whatever I do in one event will automatically triggers the other. I have tried changing the events, but so far the result simply worse. Using: if (LastName_textbox.Text = "") did not help either.
2. How do I combine Last Name and First Name as one index?

I apologise if this question has appeared or sounded ambiguous. I suppose I do not know how to phrase the search to get something similar to my problem and English is not my first language. Any help is very much appreciated .Thanks.

Here is part of the codes:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{
public partial class frmContact : Form
{
    //declare file to save all contacts    
    private string fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Contacts.txt";
    //create temporary file for updating and deleting contacts        
    private string newContacts = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\newContacts.txt";

    public frmContact()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmContact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create Contacts.txt if it does not exist
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Create(fileName).Close();
            MessageBox.Show("New " + fileName +"  Has Been Created");
            tbLast.Select();
        }
        //if file already exists
        else
        {
            StreamReader readOb = new StreamReader(fileName);
            using (readOb)
            { 
                while (!readOb.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string rdLine = readOb.ReadLine(); //read data in file by line
                    string[] tmpArr = rdLine.Split(',');
                    lbContact.Items.Add(tmpArr[0] + "," + tmpArr[1]);
                }
                tbLast.Select();
            }

        }
    }

    private void lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show details of contact selected in listbox
        string findNames = lbContact.GetItemText(lbContact.SelectedItem);
        StreamReader obRead = new StreamReader(fileName);
        using (obRead)
        {
            while (!obRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                string rdLine = obRead.ReadLine();
                if (rdLine.StartsWith(findNames))
                {
                    string[] tmpArr = rdLine.Split(',');
                    tbLast.Text = tmpArr[0];
                    tbFirst.Text = tmpArr[1].Trim();
                    tbAddr.Text = tmpArr[2].Trim();
                    tbSub.Text = tmpArr[3].Trim();
                    tbPost.Text = tmpArr[4].Trim();
                    tbEmail.Text = tmpArr[5].Trim();
                    tbPhone.Text = tmpArr[6].Trim();
                    tbMob.Text = tmpArr[7].Trim();
                }
            }
            lbContact.SelectedIndex = lbContact.FindString(findNames);
        }
    }

    private void tbLast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbContact.SelectedItem = lbContact.FindString(tbLast.Text);
    }
```

Comment: If it's winforms you'd do well to tag accordingly. Also, please show some code.

Comment: Oh, what tag should I use?

Comment: The 'winforms' tag. and FYI (for future questions you ask) the reason I'm asking for code is so that your question becomes a lot more specific to the context in which you're asking. This site is, primarily, for specific technical questions and it's a lot more productive to work with what you already have as opposed to a textual description from which we code from scratch.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tips. The code is a lot longer, but I did not copy the parts for Add and Delete Button functions. Not sure... since it is not related to the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's right, keep it as succinct as possible. I'll have a proper look at this in a min for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will keep trying some other ways in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple (but kind of ugly solution) would consist in using a boolean value to inform your `lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged` method that the index was manually changed thanks to the code. A class member would do the job, something like:

```
private bool fromCode;

private void lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fromCode)
       return;

    // Do the job
}

private void tbLast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fromCode = true;
    lbContact.SetSelected(lbContact.FindString(tbLast.Text), true);
    fromCode = false;
}
```

**[Personal remark]**
I would also create a `Contact` struct/class to store your information along with a collection in your form so that you only have to access your file twice:

- At loading, so that you can populate your collection
- At closing, so that you can save the changes to your file

**[Update]**
My last remark can be not relevant as I do not have the context in which you are developing your application, that's why I said it was a personal point of view, you don't have to do it.

**[Update 2]**

What you can do to avoid access your file each time your `lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged` event is called:

- Create a structure or a class to store your contacts information (firstname, lastname, adress, ...)
- Create a collection (as a class member of your form) that will contain the contacts (like a `List<Contact>`)
- In your `frmContact_Load` method, fill this collection with the data contained in the file instead of populating your listbox
- So that in your `lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged` method you will search inside the collection instead of opening your file
- Your Add() and Delete() operations must also modify the collection and not the file anymore
- Remember to save your collection back to your file at application closing

Hope it helped.

Comment: I like this. Either way, the OP needs some way of determining whether this event was invoked from an explicit click or from the `TextChanged` event and I think this does the job. +1.

Comment: Hey Tim, I have tried that before but it did not work and I think because those two events trigger each other?
And do you mind to give me the details on the remark? I do not get it. The instruction is to use suitable array, which is why I do not use list (unless list is in array category?) Thanks for helping.

Comment: They only trigger each other because you set the text of the "tbLast" textbox in the "lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged" method. But if you don't set it when the index is modified by the "tbLast_TextChanged" method, there won't be any problems.

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't get what you mean. So what should I do to stop the trigger?

Comment: I updated my code, try this new one. I tested it on my computer and it works.

Comment: Thanks although I still got this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'. But at least one step forward. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And if you don't mind to give me a bit more details on how to create struct/class? For future reference, something to look up later :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, yeah my bad. This happens because of the `SetSelected()` method. It doesn't accept a negative index but the `FindString()` method will return -1 if no matches were found.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining. Now at least I don't have to try finding the explanation, only need to find another solution to it. Really appreciate it. I can finally move forward now :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (for whoever encounters similar problem), the answer is in the textbox.focused :) and combined with listbox.setselected from Tim.

```
    private void tbLast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbLast.Focused && tbLast.Text != "")
        {
            if (lbContact.FindString(tbLast.Text) > -1)
            {
                lbContact.SetSelected(lbContact.FindString(tbLast.Text), true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void lbContact_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show details of contact selected in listbox
        string findNames = lbContact.GetItemText(lbContact.SelectedItem);
        StreamReader obRead = new StreamReader(fileName);
        using (obRead)
        {
            while (!obRead.EndOfStream)
            {
                string rdLine = obRead.ReadLine();
                if (rdLine.StartsWith(findNames))
                {
                    string[] tmpArr = rdLine.Split(',');
                    if (!tbLast.Focused)
                    {
                        tbLast.Text = tmpArr[0];
                        tbFirst.Text = tmpArr[1].Trim();
                        tbAddr.Text = tmpArr[2].Trim();
                        tbSub.Text = tmpArr[3].Trim();
                        tbPost.Text = tmpArr[4].Trim();
                        tbEmail.Text = tmpArr[5].Trim();
                        tbPhone.Text = tmpArr[6].Trim();
                        tbMob.Text = tmpArr[7].Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
            lbContact.SelectedIndex = lbContact.FindString(findNames);
        }
    }
```